# Thermostat wiring question (Boiler and Air Handler)

Tags: wiring, thermostat

Because I have both a boiler (in the basement) and A/C air handler (attic), I have two bundles of wires at my thermostat.  One bundle has wires that connect to RH and G, and the other has W and Y.   Also, btw one wire in each bundle (both blue) are wire nutted together. I went to the attic to check the connections at the A/C air handler and R and G are wired, so it seems I know which bundle goes where. Also the blue wire is connected to the X terminal.  I haven't checked the circuit board at the Boiler, yet.

So my question(s).  Like many, I'd like to install a Wifi thermostat and want a C wire connection.  I have spare wires in each bundle. There's empty W1, W2 and Y terminals at the air handler, but no C terminal.  Can any of these be used as C?  Also, why are the blue wires wire nutted?  I've attached a picture of the schematic at the air handler (happy to take additional pics as needed).  Also I don't understand why the Y terminal isn't used at A/C air handler, and rather the Y wire from the thermostat seems to go to the boiler.!!?

EDIT: I've now added pics of the boiler schematic and board (second and third pics, respectively). I have some theories on the whole configuration below pics.

[image: A/C air handler schematic]

[image: Boiler schematic]

[image: boiler control board]

Here are a few theories: 1) The W wire from thermostat links to T terminal on boiler as power, with the X wire from the airhandler providing the return via the TV terminal at boiler to X terminal at Air handler  2) The Y terminal is not used at Air handler because it's not linked to anything.  Instead the Y wire runs from thermostat down to basement, using the thermostat bundle that's heading in that direction then splitting off to AC condenser outside, likely also with the X wire from the air handler as common.  3) The X wires (blue) are wire nutted since they are not needed to power the thermostat and instead provides the common loop for condenser (and boiler?) 4) Leaving everything as is, I can take a spare wire at the Air handler, connect it also to the X terminal and connect that to C at the new thermostat.

Comment: Is the pump at the boiler? And what causes the pump to turn on? For example is it switched on by the boiler or does it have its own relay?

Comment: Are you referring to the water circulation pump?  It's at the boiler and I believe turns on by the boiler

Comment: T is the W terminal on your boiler aquastat, with W/Z being your aquastat's C terminal, BTW

Comment: Thanks. I did read that elsewhere.  Unfortunately I don't have a spare wire from boiler to thermostat to connect W/Z to C.

Answer (score 1):

I believe **in this case** the X terminal is what is now called the C terminal - it's the "other side of the transformer connected to the R terminal", without anything switched from it.

i.e. power flowing from R to X won't cause something else to happen at your air handler, whereas power flowing from R to G or R to W1 will, and no power will flow from R to Y or R to W2 since they are not connected at all.

This is by no means the "only meaning" of X in thermostat wiring, - in some cases it evidently is used for auxiliary heat. However, it is [known to be equivalent to C](https://www.thermostatforums.com/showthread.php?102-X-Wire-same-as-C-Wire) for some makes and eras, and the schematic shows that to be the case for your air handler.

Comment: Thanks.  So why is this X terminal wire connected (by wire nut) to the blue wire in the other bundle at the thermostat?  Other wires at the thermostat are simply left unconnected if not used.

Comment: Have you looked at the boiler-end connections yet? There are several possible explanations. I've answered what I can answer from the information provided.

Comment: I have added boiler-end pics above, and theories (which will be deleted/amended) as new insights emerge.  Thanks.